# Why Quarz.net job firing multipule time for same trigger instance c#

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I am trying to build triggers for a job in Quarz.net based on config settings something like

```
  var keysArray = [1,2]
                keysArray.ForEach(key =>
                {
                //schedule will be unique for a key
                        var schedule = AppConfig.Get($"CronJobs.{key}.TimeSheetAutoSubmit.Schedule.QuarzExpression") ?? "0 30 23 * * ?";
                        var timeZoneId = AppConfig.Get($"CronJobs.{key}.TimeSheetAutoSubmit.TimeZoneId") ?? "India Standard Time";

                        var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                            .ForJob(jobDetail)
                            .WithCronSchedule(schedule, x => x
                            .InTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneId)))
                            .WithIdentity($"TimeSheetAutoSubmitTrigger_{key}")
                            .WithDescription($"ConfigKey_{key}")
                            .StartNow()
                            .Build();
                        Scheduler.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);

                });
```

Works fine but problem is trigger is firing multiple times when i check the logs

```
2017-03-16 12:04:12,247 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1] INFO  UnitedLex.Services.JobHandlers.timesheetautosubmit - job started
2017-03-16 12:04:13,510 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2] INFO  UnitedLex.Services.JobHandlers.timesheetautosubmit - job started
2017-03-16 12:04:13,710 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2] INFO  UnitedLex.Services.JobHandlers.timesheetautosubmit - job started
```

Don't know what i am doing wrong here....

Comment: I got my issue was in my cron expression that was "* 30 23 * * ?" which i change to "0 30 23 * * ?"

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong but I think it's normal because your job builder/scheduler is inside a foreach, the amount of times it gets fired is equal to the length of your array.

Comment: thanks i got my issue was in my cron expression that was "* 30 23 * * ?" which i change to "0 30 23 * * ?"

Answer (score 0):

If you want your jobs to not run in concurrent mode use this attribute `[DisallowConcurrentExecution]` on your job definition.

This way the next job trigger will wait for the current running job to finish.